# Python import cv2 recognised but doesn't work

Tags: python, opencv, import

I use windows and Eclipse as IDE. I have installed opencv-python and numpy with pip.
When I try to do:

```
import cv2
```

It seems that it is recognised, but I'm not able to use not even a method of this library.
In "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages" I have both:
opencv_python-3.2.0.7.dist-info
cv2
as folders.

In cv2 i have:

```
__init__
__init__
cv2.pyd
opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll
```

I don't understand what's wrong, the import works but then methods are not recognised. 
For example:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('tmp.png')
cv2.imwrite("tmp.jpg", image)
```

"imread" and "imwrite" are said to be "undefined variable from import cv2".
Any suggest?
Thank you in advance,
Antonio

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my first question, I did a small mess. If something is unclear please ask me.

Comment: What was the issue exactly? The proposed edit doesn't make it much clearer. Can you _edit_ the question yourself to clarify?

Comment: Have you called your own script `cv2.py`?

Comment: No I didn't, it has a different name. The problem is that eclipse import correctly cv2 but then the methods are not recognised.